# Uncaught Error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I am new in angular.js. I intend to create drop down on run time with angular. I have created a javascript function which creates normal input box on ajax success(not included in code) and with each input box there will be a drop down.I am following javascript modeule pattern to create input box**

```
<html ng-app="rightPaneApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
FileUploadRightPane={};
FileUploadRightPane.createTable=function(){
    var allRows=null;
    for(var i=0,j=$("#appendTable thead tr td").length;i<j;i++){
        console.log($("#appendTable thead tr td")[i].innerText);
        var tableRows ='<tr id="createTable_'+i+'"><td>'+$("#appendTable thead tr td")[i].innerText+'</td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="radio" name="mapRadio"></td></tr>';
        allRows+=tableRows;
        }
    $("#mapTable").append(allRows);


    var myAppModule = angular.module('rightPaneApp',[]).controller('dropDown',function($scope){

        var dropdown={};
        $scope.columnType={

                options:[
                    {id:"varchar",type:"String",name:"string"},
                    {id:"integer",type:"Integer",name:"integer"},
                    {id:"boolean",type:"Boolean",name:"boolean"},
                    {id:"date",type:"Date",name:"date"},
                    {id:"char",type:"Character",name:"character"}
                ]};
            dropDownMenu='<td><div ng-controller="dropDown"><select ng-model="columnType" ng-options="obj.id as obj.type for obj in columnType.options"></select></div></td>';  
    console.log("Hello")
            $('body').find("[id^=createTable_]").append(dropDownMenu);
        })   
}
</script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="dropDown" id="body">

    <table id="mapTable">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**

```
But I am getting this error 

    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module rightPaneApp due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'rightPaneApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that ...<omitted>...0)
```

**

Comment: Comma missing between string and array here? `('rightPaneApp'[])`

Comment: sorry that comma got deleted during modification, but comma is there in code. I have edited it

Comment: Why there are so many issue on angularJs, it means it's popular? or it's too abstract that make people hard to use?

Comment: @flybird A lot of the times, it's because people that have a jQuery background, try to write an AngularJs app in the jQuery way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding explicit annotations using the array style and $inject property.

```
angular.module('rightPaneApp',[]).controller('dropDown', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

Example from AngularJS:

```
angular.module('ngAppStrictDemo', [])
// BadController will fail to instantiate, due to relying on automatic function annotation,
// rather than an explicit annotation
.controller('BadController', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
})
// Unlike BadController, GoodController1 and GoodController2 will not fail to be instantiated,
// due to using explicit annotations using the array style and $inject property, respectively.
.controller('GoodController1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
}])
.controller('GoodController2', GoodController2);
function GoodController2($scope) {
  $scope.name = "World";
}
GoodController2.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp